# Read a CSV file with Json column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've a CSV file that contains couple of JSON columns and I'm reading it using python panda. The sample file data looks like the following :

```
12345,67890,{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},abcdefgh,{"key4":"value4"}
12345,67890,NONE,abcdefgh,{"key4":"value4"}
```

I'm using `,` as a separator while reading the CSV but this is causing an issue since the JSON data also contain `,` and eventually the row isn't correctly delimited.

`pd.read_csv('s3://bucket-name/file.csv', sep=",")`

I've also tried another regex `[a-zA-Z0-9],|[}],` as a separator but this removes the last character(1 character before `,`) from the column data.

Comment: This is not valid csv for any reasonable csv reader.  Usually, if text fields have commas, there is a quoting mechanism.

Comment: Can the json be nested, i.e., brackets within brackets?

Comment: You could maybe solve this with regex backreferences. But this seems like a very ambiguous file format.

Comment: @Dan, No the json isn't nested.

Comment: If not nested, first just run this over every line into a temp file: `line.replace('"', r'\"').replace(',{', ',"{').replace('}', '}"')` and see if you can parse with normal csv reader / pandas csv then.

Answer (score 0):

We can load the file correctly if we don't take the commas followed by the json element.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

input_csv = io.StringIO("""
                12345, 67890,{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},abcdefgh,{"key4":"value4"}
                12345,67890,NONE, "abcdefgh",{"key4":"value4"}
                """)

df = pd.read_csv(input_csv, header=None,
                 sep=r',(?! ?\"\w+\"(?=:))', engine='python')
print(df.to_string())

---------------------------------------

       0      1                                                   2            3                  4
0  12345  67890  {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}     abcdefgh  {"key4":"value4"}
1  12345  67890                                                NONE   "abcdefgh"  {"key4":"value4"}
```

> " ,(?! ?"\w+"(?=:)) " g , matches the character , with index 4410
> (2C16 or 548) literally (case sensitive) Negative Lookahead (?!
> ?"\w+"(?=:)) Assert that the Regex below does not match   matches
> the character   with index 3210 (2016 or 408) literally (case
> sensitive) ? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as
> many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) " matches the
> character " with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)
> \w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
>
> - matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) " matches the
>   character " with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)
>   Positive Lookahead (?=:) Assert that the Regex below matches : matches
>   the character : with index 5810 (3A16 or 728) literally (case
>   sensitive)